# Self hosted mac build agent for , skipping upload and download of source code or binary

Tags: xamarin, azure-pipelines

I have a mac machine which would work as a build agent. Ideally, what the build definition would do is when my commit triggers a build, it will upload the code to the build agent that I have (from  VSTS -> Mac Agent) and then build it.

However, I want to skip the uploading part (uploading from VSTS to my build agent) assuming I will be having the latest copy of source code on my Mac.

**Why I want to do this?**
Since I have my own build agent, my own internet. It just doesn't make sense to charge build minutes consumed for uploading / downloading the source code and binaries to my self hosted Mac Agent.

Another reason why I want to do it is the internet connection being slow, upload - download will eat up a lot of minutes on my VSTS which is just super expensive unnecessarily. Also the VSO-Agent / VSTS are super buggy at this stage with almost NO support which is sad from Xamarin / Microsoft.

Btw, [I am following this article](http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/xamarin-dev-ops-with-vsts-setup-ios-ci-builds-with-macincloud/).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to skip the "Get sources" step. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

By the way, if you have deployed your own build agent, then it won't be charged when run build task with it. Build minutes charging is only for Hosted Build Agent.

Comment: Hi Eddie, does that mean all the builds that we trigger on our own host will be free of cost?

Comment: Btw, which agent should I prefer using on our mac? vso-agent or vsts-agent?

Comment: @RahulPatil What do you mean? VSO is the legacy name for VSTS.

Comment: I see two repositories - https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent and https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent. Both do similar job.

Comment: @RahulPatil Use vsts-agent, vso-agent page is Deprecated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114001/discussion-between-rahul-patil-and-eddie-msft).

Answer (score 0):

The "Skip source download" option has recently been released to Visual Studio Team Services and should also be available to TFS 2017 users. You can find a checkbox on the repository tab to skip the fetch sources step.